# Java - чистый код на примере простого цикла

Tags: java, инспекция-кода, while

Сразу скажу -  в java начинающий, как сделать цикл более "грамотным"  и "логичным"?

```
public void scanner(EnigmaService enigma, String cypher_mode){

     //enigma - обьект, который имеет метод enchiper i deschiper
     // cypher_mode -  "-е" или "-d"

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(scan.hasNextLine()){

        if(cypher_mode.equals("-e")){
            System.out.println(enigma.encipher(scan.nextLine()));
        }
        else{
            if(cypher_mode.equals("-d")){
                System.out.println(enigma.decipher(scan.nextLine()));
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поскольку строковые значения `-d` и `-e` имеют отношение к параметрам командной строки, т.е. к по сути к пользовательскому интерфейсу, а не непосредственно к логике программы, можно завести enum.

```
public enum CipherMode {
    ENCIPHER, DECIPHER;
}
```

Где-то у вас будет код вида:

```
CipherMode mode = null;
if (args.contains("-d")) { mode = DECIPHER }
if (args.contains("-e")) { mode = ENCIPHER; }
...
if (mode == null) {
    System.out.println("Не указан режим работы шифра.");
    return;
}
```

Дальше уже используйте этот enum:

```
public void scanner(EnigmaService enigma, CypherMode cipherMode){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(scan.hasNextLine()){
        String line = scan.nextLine();
        switch(cipherMode) {
            case ENCIPHER: enigma.encipher(line); break;
            case DECIPHER: enigma.decipher(line); break;
        }
}
```

PS. Подчеркивания в именах в Java не приняты.

Comment: Отличный вариант, воспользовался . Единственное что - String line = scan.nextLine(); - не работает через присвоение к стрингу. Может знаете почему? Работает лишь напрямую с scan.nextLine()

Comment: Ошибку не находит, но нет никакого outputa

Comment: А не логичнее сделать класс со ссылкой на элемент encripter/decriptor класса EnigmaService и создать экземпляр, ссылающийся в зависимости от -d/-e на нужный метод? Тогда `if`  выносится из цикла.

Comment: Можно, но городить ооп на ровном месте...

Comment: Ну, на Си без всякого ООП, указатель на функцию это весьма логично (и никаких огородов, которые вынуждает делать Java)